# webview.URL?.absoluteString returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nsurl, wkwebview

my `webview.URL?.absoluteURL.absoluteString` is returning nil. This is a `WKWebview`, not a `UIWebVIew`, so `webview.request?.URL?.absoluteString` will not work for this. I have also tried `webview.URL?.absoluteString`.

The URL is set in another UIViewController class. The webview itself loads properly, so I know .URL is not nil. (use cmd/ctrl+f '//Problem' to find line):

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    gestureRecognizers = [UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"moveWindow:")]
    //Change aspects of our view (width, height, color, etc)
    header.frame.size.width=frame.size.width
    header.frame.size.height=45
    header.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    //addSubview(header)
    windowMask.frame=frame
    stackButton.frame=frame
    windowMask.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    windowMask.clipsToBounds=true

    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowRadius = 5
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    layer.cornerRadius = 6
    backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Window Texture.png")!)
    //opaque=false
    //backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    addSubview(windowMask)
    dragArea.frame.size.width=frame.size.width-120
    dragArea.frame.origin.x=40
    dragArea.frame.origin.x=40
    //addSubview(dragArea)
    //Our webview for... well, isn't it obvious?
    webview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, frame.width, frame.height-40)
    webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures=true
    windowMask.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.width, frame.height)
    windowMask.addSubview(webview)
    //The back button
    bbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Back"), forState: .Normal)
    bbutton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 30, 30)
    windowMask.addSubview(bbutton)
    bbutton.addTarget(self, action: "bbuttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    //The large button to select a window in the Stack menu
    stackButton.addTarget(self, action: "stackSelected:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    //The resize button for making the window fullscreen
    rbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Max"), forState: .Normal)
    rbutton.frame = CGRectMake(frame.width-60, 7, 25, 25)
    windowMask.addSubview(rbutton)
    rbutton.addTarget(self, action: "rbuttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    //The X button for closing a window
    xbutton.frame = CGRectMake(frame.width-35, 5, 30, 30)
    xbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Close"), forState: .Normal)
    windowMask.addSubview(xbutton)
    xbutton.addTarget(self, action: "xbuttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    //The button for adjusting window size
    abutton.frame = CGRectMake(frame.width-20, frame.height-20, 20, 20)
    abutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Resize"), forState: .Normal)
    windowMask.addSubview(abutton)
    abutton.addTarget(self, action: "abuttonDragged:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    //The task button
    taskButton.frame.size=CGSizeMake(60,60)
    taskButton.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    taskButton.frame.origin=CGPointMake(CGFloat(system.windows.count)*60,60)
    taskButton.addTarget(self, action: "taskSelected:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    //Problem here:
    let imgURL = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/s2/favicons?domain="+(self.webview.URL?.absoluteString)!)
    print(self.webview.URL?.absoluteURL.absoluteString)
    let imageRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
        imageRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
        completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse?,data: NSData?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.taskButton.setImage(UIImage(data: data!),forState: .Normal)
            }
    })
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.frame.origin.y=50
        self.taskButton.frame.origin.y=0
    })
}
```

The func in another UIViewController class that sets the URL. Site in web view itself loads properly.

```
func addWindowButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://google.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let newView = Window(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-200,self.view.frame.size.height, 400, 300))
    if !system.stacked {
        view.addSubview(newView)
        newView.webview.loadRequest(request)
        system.windows.append(newView)
        taskView.addSubview(newView.taskButton)
        newView.windowID=system.windows.count
        taskView.contentSize.width=CGFloat(system.windows.count)*60
    }
    taskView.contentSize.width=CGFloat(system.windows.count)*60
}
```

Comment: if you are already implementing the WKNavigationDelegate you can check  navigationAction.request.URL inside decidePolicyForNavigationAction method.

Comment: What class is this `init` of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the absoluteString attribute of URL.

```
webView.URL?.absoluteString
```

the URL read-only property will get a value after you call loadRequest.
Here is a sample:

```
func loadWebPage(url : NSURL!)
{
  let urlbefore = webView.URL?.absoluteString
  print (urlbefore)

  let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url, cachePolicy:NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval:15.0)
  self.webView.loadRequest(theRequest)

  let urlafter = webView.URL?.absoluteString
  print (urlafter)     
}
```

This will print the following:

```
nil
Optional("https://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: where did you call it? please show us your code.
If you call it in didFinishNavigation or didFailNavigation delegate, you will get a value.

Comment: I checked your code and nowhere did I find the part where you call loadRequest function of WKWebView. That is the reason why you are getting a nil.

Comment: Did you set the webView  of this class to that of another class? From your code above, it seems like you are creating a new webView here. And that could be the reason why it is nil.

Comment: that is strange. URL should not be nil if you wkwebview loaded properly. Can you show the source code of other class?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I called the attribute before I called loadRequest and URL was nil. But after loadRequest is called, it returned a value.

Comment: Added the code of the other class. It is called by a UIButton

Comment: my suggestion is you try calling loadRequest on your init function just before calling the another loadRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `webView.URL?` is nil because it was not set.

If you expect it to be set, make sure that the code setting it is actually executed **before** the code in which you want to read it.

Comment: Yes, but it may not have a value *at the time you are checking it.* Are you sure that the URL isn't being set after the view is initialized?